# Error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'mfcs110.lib'

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-2019

In VS2019 , I am getting Error  LNK1181 cannot open input file 'mfcs110.lib' when i compile C++ code in Release Mode.

The Code works fine when i compile in Debugging Mode.

Note:  Migrated the Project from VS2012 to VS2019

Answer (score 1):

[Linker Tools Error LNK1181](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1181?view=vs-2019). I suggest you should ensure any files referenced on the linker line are present on the system. Also ensure there is a /LIBPATH statement for each directory containing a linker-dependent file.

Right-click the project, and then click Properties -> Linker -> General. In the Additional Library Directories field, specify the required library path.

**Note**: the selection in the "Configuration" in the upper left corner of our properties dialog should correspond to the "Debug" or "Release" selected at runtime. I suggest you could select "All Configurations".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have searched for mfcs110.lib as linker input in the 'Release' configuration project properties (not the 'Debug' properties). The project properties pages are independent of your active configuration setting, so it is easy to check the properties in the wrong configuration.  Look in the Linker Input tab, under 'Additional dependencies'.